# Create Angular components in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I've been using VS Code for ASP.Net + Angular projects, and there I could've generated a new Angular component using some extensions from the context menu:

[image: click]

Now after I've migrated to Visual Studio 2019 (not Code) and making a project with ASP.NET Core + Angular, I don't know how to generate an Angular component, because I'm not able to find anything related to it in the menu.

[image: click]

So how do you generate an Angular component in VS?

Are you using VS Code for Client-side and VS for back-end or is there any extension that I'm missing for VS?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this in VS from what I can see.  You can run the CLI but VS will not load the results into your project.  If you right-click to manually add, it will omit the folder and just bring the files in up a level from where they actually exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any extension just use angular cli. Open new terminal in the Visual Studio Code from  Terminal -> New Terminal. Then write on the console ng generate component "component-name" or ng g c "component-name"

Comment: He is asking how to do it with visual studio 2019, not with code.

Answer (score 2):

From First image Click on **Open In Integrated Terminal**

or use below key to open terminal:
ctrl + shift + `

run command
**ng g c component name**

You can check documentation for command

https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Comment: View -> Terminal (ctrl + ö)

Comment: He was asking about VS2019, not VS Code

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [Angular Item Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xpasza.Angular4ItemTemplates) by Pavel Agarkov available in visual studio for adding angular components